# How to access JOBJECT element and change its value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, object

In my controller I have this method :

```
public Tuple<DataTable, DataTable> GraphData(JObject jsonData)
```

The object has this data :

```
"Wgraph": {
    "GraphType": "Line",
 "XAxisList": [
      {
        "Dimension": "[DimCustomer].[AddressLine1].[AddressLine1]",
        "HIERARCHY": "[DimCustomer].[AddressLine1]"
      }
    ],
    "YAxisList": [
      {
        "MeasureExpression": "undefined",
        "ChartType": "",
        "IsSecondaryAxis": "False"
      },
      {
        "MeasureExpression": "undefined",
        "ChartType": "",
        "IsSecondaryAxis": "False"
      }
    },
"DashboardName": "NewTest"
    }
```

What I am trying to do it access the second value of  `"IsSecondaryAxis":"False"` and change its value to `TRUE`

How can I retrieve this data ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can access the second element of the array using:

```
var arr = jsonData["Wgraph"]["YAxisList"] as JArray;

arr[1]["IsSecondaryAxis"] = true;
```

Comment: Let me try it now . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the first response of Lee Gunn, but using a dynamic object:

```
var arr = ((dynamic) jsonData).Wgraph.YAxisList;
arr[1]["IsSecondaryAxis"] = true;
```

The result is the same. Regards.

Comment: One more thing: 
I want to put an IF condition like when YAxisList.length >1 or smth like that do the code that you send me .

But newton json list array does not accept length or count

Comment: When I try to run your code it says the name 'o' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Besa JArray has a Count property.

Comment: @Besa Sorry, I was testing the code locally. "o" is your "jsonData". I've updated it.